# How to assign a class to ID - css

Tags: css

I have this code. I need it to cover a specific ID #carousel02, but I don't know how to do it.

```
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + 
    .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
     transition: none;
     }
     .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
     .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
     .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
      position: relative;
      }
```

I tried different variants.

```
#carousel02 .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
```

or

```
#carousel02 .carousel-inner #carousel02 .carousel-item#carousel02.active:not(#carousel02 .carousel-item-right):not(#carousel02 .carousel-item-left)
```

Comment: You need to remove the spaces. `#foo .bar` selects elements with class `bar`, that are _descendants of_ `#foo`. `#foo.bar` selects an element that has the ID `foo`  _and_ the class `bar`.

Comment: (Btw., that is stuff you should be learning from a beginner’s tutorial IMHO, instead of asking about it here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use ID selector before assigning each parent element.

```
  #carousel02 .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + 
.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
 transition: none;
 }
 #carousel02 .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
 #carousel02 .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
 #carousel02 .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide additional information in answer instead of just posting a code